# Как в OWL Carousel управлять слайдами нестандартными кнопками?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне нужно перехватить обработчики кнопок навигации внешнего подключенного слайдера. Разметка в силу некоторых причин не позволяет сделать корректно кнопки слайдера, и мне нужно передать на свои кнопки обработчики события навигации

Comment: А вы знаете какой обработчик хотите прикрепить?

Comment: Что за слайдер? Наверняка у него есть методы для листания слайдов вперед-назад. Вот их и вызывайте по нажатию на ваши кнопки

Comment: Да, конечно, мне нужен лишь js код, а точнее jquery

Comment: Я использую слайдер owl-carousel

Comment: В комментариях можно указывать пользователя, которому вы отвечаете через @имяпользователя

Comment: @tutankhamun ок, по поводу вопроса можете показать как это сделать в jQuery?

Comment: скройте дефолтные кнопки, нарисуйте свои а на них просто вызывайте клик по скрытых дефолтных....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим у вас есть кнопки вперед-назад

```
<div class="js-owl-prev">⇽</div>
<div class="js-owl-next">⇾</div>
```

Чтобы с их помощью листать слайды, нужно вызывать методы инстанса слайдера

```
//допустим инстанс содержится в переменной slider, тогда
$('.js-owl-prev').on('click', function() {
     slider.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
});
$('.js-owl-next').on('click', function() {
     slider.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
});
```

Comment: Даже не подумал, что нужно просто вызывать встроенные функции, спасибо) Ваш ответ навел меня на документацию по тому слайдеру, оказалось у него как раз таки есть методы для таких случаев